# FTP over SSL to z/OS to List Directory Files

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest, zos

I'm trying to connect to a z/OS FTP server to download files but first I need to list them in order to find out which is the most recent. The server has an unknown certificate I have to trust and I've used the code below which included a warning about not using in production

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate (
        object s,
        X509Certificate cert, 
        X509Chain chain, 
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolErrors) { return true; };
```

I'm having a really hard time listing the files in the directory I'm after. It seems z/OS is a real pain. I basically need to connect to the FTP server over SSL which I've managed to do but changing working directory has proven to be difficult.

```
string ftpPath = @"ftp://192.168.1.1/'THE.DIRECTORY.I.NEED.TO.CONNECT.TO'";
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteFtpPath);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
request.KeepAlive = request.UsePassive = request.EnableSsl = true;
```

> Am I connecting to the working directory I need with my `ftpPath`
>   string? If not, what's the proper way of changing working directory? The only way I've seen to do it after some google research is to include it in my `ftpPath` string.

The error I get doing it this way is given `550 No data sets found...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL for the `ListDirectory` method should in general end with a slash.

Without a slash, results tend to be uncertain, largely depending on the FTP server implementation.